# Wordpress: Contact Form 7 accepts one email address but not another

Tags: email, wordpress

I've been using Contact Form 7 in Wordpress without too many problems. In a current installation, I can send mail to webmaster@domain.com but get an error when trying to send mail to user1@domain.com. I've checked this Stack Overflow ticket:

[Wordpress - Contact Form 7 Not Sending to Certain Email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472848/wordpress-contact-form-7-not-sending-to-certain-email)

But enabling the SMTP mail plugin doesn't modify the behavior of the bug, and the mail server is not external (like the ticket in question). Any idea what the issue might be? Thanks!

EDIT: user@domain.com is a valid email address and also succeeds when running it against open source online email checkers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kind of a hack, but I had this happen to me when I tried to have the emails sent outside of the domain to a gmail account.  I ended up adding `CC: youremail@gmail.com` to the Additional Headers and it worked well afterwards.

Comment: Since you're the only guy who commented, I'll accept the answer! We used a different plug-in and it ended up working, but thanks for the good idea.

Comment: What plugin did you end up going with?  It'd be nice to see what solved your problem.

Comment: please add which plugin was used I could use it right now

Comment: It seems @MichaelB has never been back to SO after that question.